# Docker for Jobs

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to understand if this is a valid use case for Docker.

Suppose I am creating a python application, and the user submits a job of a specific type. I would like to then use `docker run` programmatically to start a docker image that is designed to process the job. The docker image would need to be able to receive the job, and then exit sending me a message that the job is successful.

Does this make sense? How could this be done using python? How can I observe docker containers and their status?

Or would it make more sense for the docker image to simply run on a loop, looking for jobs from a shared volume?

Comment: It seems like a lot of overhead to create and tear down a docker image for each request.  Although, if you expect very little traffic, I suppose it could be more efficient.

Comment: What is a "job" in this context?

Comment: This is a random R script running in its own container. It will save a pdf to a shared volume. This R script takes JSON as input - and finds files to process in a shared volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally crazy idea but, you most likely would be better off having only one container which contains a server, that listens for requests to run a "job", and then runs the relevant R code.  No need to start a container for each request if the image you're running will be the same every time, instead you just send an HTTP request.

If you *really* want to manipulate Docker with Python you can use [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py).  Docker Compose is based on this library.